# Nature of an HD clone

Tags: windows, passwords, disk-cloning

I cloned an SSD from a device to another device's SSD. The SSD as well as the Surface 2 Pro are the exact same model, however the wifi password got lost. 
This isn't necessarily a problem, I'm just curious where and how this password was stored and why it got lost. The operating system is Windows 8.1 and the devices were Surface 2 Pro.

Comment: Did you have any other passwords stored that were also lost? I wonder if the credential files were copied but remain encrypted and therefore unusable until decrypted... See [here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/find-hidden-saved-passwords-windows/) for details on the credential manager of windows systems.

Comment: On the page it says that the credentials are unlocked via the windows password, so that should not have caused any problems as i still entered the windows password after the clone. The only difference i could think of after the clone are some hardware informations, like the mac-address or similar. I did a bit for bit copy so the ssd itself should be identical.

Comment: Yes they are indeed, so if it was a bit-for-bit copy and you're using the same Windows password I have to say I'm stumped! If required, you could use one of the programs on the aforementioned page to retrieve passwords from the original drive, but this is a puzzling occurrence nonetheless...

Comment: Maybe the Surface's TPM has something to do with this.

Comment: What method of "cloning" did you use... um... CloneZilla, your own custom C# code, or what?

Comment: @Sam3000 thank you, but i have the password. I am just curious and want to understand the reason as this could cause problems in different situations.

Comment: @Twisty thank you for the hint, i'll read into it.

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous i used macrium free edition on bootable usb